# Class 'yii\models\user' not found in view yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using YII2 advanced and  I am trying from some hour but not any code working for me. I want to create dropdown from user table in my post page. I have found this error `Class 'yii\models\user' not found`. i have created this post with GII.  my `_form.php` code

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\models\user;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Posts */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm 
<?php/* <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->textInput(['value' => \Yii::$app->user->identity->id]) ?> 
use yii\models\user;
*/
?>

<div class="posts-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'post_title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'post_description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>



    <?php
        echo Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'author_id',ArrayHelper::map(User::find()->all(),'id','username'),['prompt'=>'Select User']);
    ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Why not working please anyone help me. 
Thanks in advence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User::find()` shows that you would use a User model, so really in uppercase as scaisEdge has answered to you.

However you have to know, in what namespace your User model is sitting. Yii2 doesn't have a User model, you have to create it. You mentioned, that you are using the advanced template. In that case you should create a User model in 'common/models/User.php' instead of 'models/User.php'. Follow the description in the [Yii2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html).

Comment: Thanks that you got my point. Now I am using use common\models\User;

Comment: Working fine. But just I am asking this is  right method? or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In php typically a class name begin with an Uppercase char so in a unix like env (with file system based on a case sensitive constrain )  this must match try

```
use yii\models\User;
```

Comment: Thanks@42.7k. I am every time looking your number. I hope one day this will  be 1000000.